ARM64 version: no vmw_pvscsi module!
Im trying to install Ubuntu (22.04.4 or 24.04) on VmWare Fusion.
Installer detects all VmWare virtual devices except PVSCSI controllers.
When I trying modprobe vmw_pvscsi, it says that module not found (on both 22.04.4 and 24.04)
